# npm run android is not working in windows 10

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cmd, npm

I'm new to React Native programming. I'm having difficulty in running my app in Android phone, because my npm run android is not working.

[Cmd result Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeR0A.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running `npm run-android` to run the app ??
to run the app you start with `react-native run-android` before it you should run it with `npm start`

this the reference https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html for starting the react native app